# Ask for WPF MVVM Data Edit Form Validation Guideline

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, input, binding

I would like to make a form for modifying data that supports validations and `[Cancel]` button.

- To display existing data on the `[Edit]` form, I bind the form with a `ViewModel` object
- To validate user input, I use `<Binding.ValidationRules>` for `TextBox` with `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` (I want to validate user inputs while they are entering values for `TextBox`)

The problem with this method is: when user clicks the `[Cancel]` button, the `ViewModel` data is already updated with the canceled form data. I don't want the `ViewModel` to be updated if user cancel the `Edit` action because it is also bounded to other views.

How could I achieve this goal? My application is not suitable for reloading `ViewModel` from a network database if user clicks `[Cancel]` button.

Comment: if your Viewmodel implement IEditableObject interface tehn you cann call CancelEdit() on your CancelCommand and all edits are removed.

Comment: This isn't magic.  You need to save the state prior to edits, then revert on cancel.  Nobody does this for you.  You need to implement it yourself.

Comment: If we have to save/revert `ViewModel` manually, then I think it is better to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` to update the `ViewModel` when `[Save]` button is clicked. But `<Binding.ValidationRules>` is only triggered when the `TextBox.Text` source is updated, and validation while user is inputting data seems impossible. Do you have any workarround for this problem?